# Electrostatic Discharge on new Workbench Setup

Tags: grounding, electrostatic

I'm setting up a table at home to do some electronics work (assembling microcomputer kits like the Maximite 2 and similar projects that require handling of sensitve IC chips).

I have a desktop lamp that is made of metal and I'd like to use it as a way to discharge any eletrostatic discharge built up on myself before handling any sensitve electronics, as I'm pretty sure the lamp's metal case (when plugged in of course) is grounded.

My question is, how do I test this? How can I be positive that when I touch this lamp I'm connected to ground (and so will discharge any electron build up on me)?

Comment: If the lamp doesn't have a three pin plug, then it doesn't have a ground wire.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the point here. If you are unfamiliar with how things work regarding protecting static sensitive devices you should use an ESD mat that is usually connected to ground via a discharge resistor (usually around 100 kΩ to 1 MΩ).

The point here is that when you place sensitive parts on the mat they remain at an ESD potential close to ground. And when you sit down to do work with those parts you firstly discharge yourself to the same potential as the mat by touching the mat and/or remaining in contact with the mat via a wrist-strap and curly wire. You are then at liberty to touch and handle the components in the full knowledge that in doing so, you won't cause an ESD event to damage them.

But, even before placing the components on the mat you have to be aware about handling. In other words, the sensitive components must be in an antistatic bag so that when you pick them up (with or without the wrist-strap), you won't cause them damage.

You then place them on the mat and only open up those parts from the packaging once you are connected to the mat and are absolutely ready to use them. The target circuit board should also be at "mat" potential so that when you place the components on the circuit board you don't create another possible ESD event.

In other words, it doesn't matter what potential the mat is really at because everything you do is relative to the mat potential. However, ground is a nice convenient point to connect the mat to.

When you grasp what is happening, you can learn how to handle components without a mat or wrist-strap but, until you grasp that, do the basics first and then learn how to handle stuff without mats and wrist-straps.

> *My question is, how do I test this? How can I be positive that when I
> touch this lamp I'm connected to ground*

Testing whether your lamp is earthed or not is largely irrelevant if you don't understand the basics and don't follow correct procedures. If you don't want to use a mat or wrist-strap, you better get to grips with how you handle components without them i.e. once you open the protective component package, you never release those components; you keep 'em in your sweaty palm/fingers and anything that you want to apply them to (like a PCB) you grasp with your spare hand to equalize potentials via your body.

Comment: This is a great response, very informative, thank you. I actually have an electrostatic mat with a wire that you're supposed to attach to a metal screw on a wall outlet, but there is no wrist strap for it. Would that work well? If I understand it right, I would set up the mat on my desk, attach the wire to the ground screw on the outlet cover, then touch the mat with my hands before opening/working with sensitive components. Is that correct? Wouldn't I also have to test that screw on the cover to make absolutely sure its actually grounded?

Comment: Ideally you would connect the mat to local reliable ground but through a 1 Mohm discharge resistor so that the mat doesn't pose an electrocution threat should you be strongly in contact with it AND touch live wires. That's the safety talk done! Regards not operating without a wrist-strap, you have to keep your wits about you and realistically, there's no big problem wrapping some wire around your wrist and connecting it to the mat. The mat is the "equipotential" point so it doesn't have to be earthed but it is preferable that it is (but via 1 Mohm).