# ESD while building a new computer?

Tags: esd

I'm building a new gaming computer, my first one, and I've been reading a lot online about grounding and ESD, but can't seem to get enough understanding on how it works and how I can prevent damage. For context, I live in a small apartment on an upper floor, and every floor is covered in wall-to-wall rug, except the tiny kitchen and tiny bathroom. I have radiators and obviously wall sockets, but I do not have any tools laying around besides the very basic toolkit (screwdriver, hammer etc). I did purchase a set of anti static gloves but now I've read that it may not be enough for ESD protection.

My last part will arrive today, so I was hoping to build it tonight, but if I need to buy an antistatic mat to prevent damage I can do that. Any help would be great. Thanks

Edit: The motherboard comes in an antistatic bag and I think (?) that would be the only other antistatic related thing I have.

Comment: [Try this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/533422/electrostatic-discharge-on-new-workbench-setup/533433#533433).

Comment: Anti-static gloves may help. But the main requirement is to keep the body grounded. This can be achieved with an [ESD wrist strap](https://cdn.cnetcontent.com/12/21/12213aa0-eb83-4a46-ac37-b57b9e79c0c2.jpg) but please note that using this strap requires a direct connection to the Earth. If the wall sockets has ground connection then it can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Get yourself an ESD wrist strap!

Comment: The completely unscientific way is to first touch a metal radiator. Then touch the metal parts of the computer chassis. Then lift the PCBs by only touching the sides and not any components. This covers some 95% of all use-cases, but it's not completely reliable. I've managed to fry a graphics card with ESD at one point, but then that's the only time I had an actual ESD accident with a PC in the past 25 years.

Comment: Then also avoid stuff that builds up ESD. Fleece jackets, cats, rubber boots...

Comment: Relative humidity is a big factor. You need to be a lot more careful in climates where the relative humidity is low (e.g. Phoenix, Arizona). If you regularly zap your hand on doorknobs, be very careful. I have never zapped my hand on a doorknob in my house (Florida, high humidity). And yes, I realize that electronics can be damaged with voltages well below the zap threshold. This is just a rough indicator of how easily static is generated in your house.

Comment: Don't wear socks and don't walk around too much before manipulating parts without touching the screw on a light switch faceplate or wall outlet faceplate first.

Comment: In the late 90s we killed the family computer with a static shock to the *external case*, but it's much harder these days.  Looking up static materials and checking what clothes you are wearing isn't a bad idea.  The wrist strap is kind of the cheap way to be sure, but for years before those were popularised we just got by with touching something grounded periodically as lundin suggests and avoid doing obviously stupid things like touching the screen of a CRT monitor.  Wear cotton.

Answer (score 2):

Many materials can generate electricity from friction, known as the [triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect).

If you have some way to increase the humidity in the room, use it. Electrostatic charge forms much easier in dry environments, and it's winter in a lot of the world, which means lower humidity and increased risk of [ESD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_discharge).

Lay out all the pieces (still in their anti-static packaging) including screwdriver, screws, etc. so that you can access everything easily. You want to move as little as possible, since movement creates static. *If you sit, you can't get back up until done.* Getting up from a chair is a prime generator of static electricity!  If someone comes to the door, sorry, they're going to have to wait.

Take everything out of their packages, place the anti-stat packages underneath, and set them back on the table. Then follow these steps to install the motherboard:

- Touch the metal case with BOTH HANDS. Seated or standing, pick one and stick with it.
- Lift the motherboard from underneath the antistatic bag only, with BOTH HANDS. Lift it about one foot, then let the bag fall back to the table.
- Remove one hand from the bare motherboard.
- Rest the free hand on the exposed metal case.
- Guide the motherboard roughly into position. Resist standing/sitting!
- Finish attaching screws and whatnot, making sure you *always touch the metal case* before and while sticking hands inside. If you have to get up or move to the other side (can't see screws) remember to always touch the metal case FIRST. This ensures that any static which might be on your body equalizes with the entire case, so a spark can't happen when you then touch the motherboard.

Repeat these steps for the CPU, CPU cooler, RAM, video card, power supply, hard drive, case fans, etc.

CD/DVD drives already come in a metal box, so are safe as long as you don't touch their gold connectors. All external connections (USB, video, keyboard, network etc.) all have anti-static protection devices built-in, so are safe.

Good luck and happy building.

Answer (score 0):

- treat everything floating as a charged voltage
- treat your hands as a discharge resistor< 1M~10M
- if you keep one hand grounded to case when you inserted ,then the charge will be equalized and thus not discharge.
- There are protection diodes that are current limited on each external interface to help protect against minor differences.

Otherwise , wear a ground strap attached to case.